# Group Davg Results by Date

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the following dataset that looks like this. I'd like to select only those who have a "1" for the `ESITwoToFive` variable and then compute the average `total_ED_LOS` for each unique dates. For example, the average for Feb 7th would only have the values from ID's 1 and 3.

```
ID  CheckinDate  ESITwoToFive    Total_ED_Los
 1   Feb 7             1               23
 2   Feb 7             0               23
 3   Feb 7             1               28
 4   Feb 8             1               43
 5   Feb 8             1               83
 6   Feb 8             0               29
 7   Feb 9             1               93
 8   Feb 9             1               77
 9   Feb 9             0               33
```

I'm using the following syntax but my output contains the same averages for every date.

```
SELECT [Fast Track Quality Research ESI Levels].checkin_date, 
DAvg("total_ed_los","Fast Track Quality Research ESI Levels","ESITwoToFive = 
'1'") AS Expr1

FROM [Fast Track Quality Research ESI Levels]
GROUP BY [Fast Track Quality Research ESI Levels].checkin_date;
```

Output that i'm getting...

```
Checkindate          Avg LOS
 Feb 7                   24
 Feb 8                   24
 Feb 9                   24
```

Desired output....

```
 Checkindate             Avg LOS
 Feb 7                   24
 Feb 8                   54
 Feb 9                   86
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the `Avg` function rather than the `DAvg` domain aggregate function, e.g.:

```sql
select t.checkin_date, avg(t.total_ed_los) as [Avg LOS]
from [Fast Track Quality Research ESI Levels] t
where t.esitwotofive = 1
group by t.checkin_date
```

The `DAvg` function in your example is calculating the average over *all* records for which `ESITwoToFive = '1'` *before* the data is aggregated by date, therefore you receive the same result for every record output by the query.

Comment: Thanks @Lee_Mac, do you know if its possible to calculate multiple averages? I'm going to post it in another question as it's somewhat different from this post.